# Firebase Realtime Database Decode with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I search for the value in the lemma key in the Realtime Database, **I can print the data, but I cannot decode it**(Console Output). I am getting the error I wrote below. What is the reason of this ? I even added CodingKeys to my response model but it didn't work.

**Decode Error:**

*keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "nouns", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "nouns", intValue: nil) ("nouns").", underlyingError: nil))*

[image]

Also, why are the lemma key and value not in quotes when printing the data?
And why do some characters look like this?
\U00e4

**Console Output:**

```
# Key: 1278, # Value: {
    accusativePlural = "Die H\U00e4mmer";
    accusativeSingular = "Den Hammer";
    // Why Der is not in String ? 
    article = Der;
    dativePlural = "Den H\U00e4mmer";
    dativeSingular = "Dem Hammer";
    genitivePlural = "Der H\U00e4mmer";
    genitiveSingular = "Des Hammers";
    // Why Hammer is not in String ? 
    lemma = Hammer;
    nominativePlural = "Die H\U00e4mmer";
    nominativeSingular = "Der Hammer";
}
```

**Code:**

```
final class RealtimeDatabaseManager {
    static let shared = RealtimeDatabaseManager()
    private let ref = Database.database().reference()
    
    private init() { }
    
    func search(with text: String) {
        print("foo search: \(text)")
        ref.child("nouns")
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "lemma")
            .queryStarting(atValue: text)
            .queryEnding(atValue: text + "\u{f8ff}")
            .observe(.value) { snapshot in
                do {
                    
                    let decoded = try snapshot.data(as: GermanNounsResponse.self)
                    print("# decoded: \(decoded.nouns)")
                } catch {
                    print("# error \(error)")
                }
                if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                    for (key, value) in snapDict {
                        print("# Key: \(key), # Value: \(value)")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Response Model:**

```
struct GermanNounsResponse: Decodable {
    let nouns: [GermanResponse]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case nouns
    }
}

struct GermanResponse: Decodable {
    let lemma: String
    let pos: String
    let article: String
    let nominativSingular: String
    let nominativPlural: String
    let akkusativSingular: String
    let akkusativPlural: String
    let dativSingular: String
    let dativPlural: String
    let genitivSingular: String
    let genitivPlural: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lemma
        case pos
        case article
        case nominativSingular
        case nominativPlural
        case akkusativSingular
        case akkusativPlural
        case dativSingular
        case dativPlural
        case genitivSingular
        case genitivPlural
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the root key of the response is actually gonna be `nouns` here. You might want to try [looping over `snapshot .children`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) and then reading the individual `GermanResponse` object from each child.

Comment: Read out all children from the snapshot with Database.database().reference().child("nouns").

Comment: Note, there is no need for all those `enum CodingKeys...`, you can remove them.
 Try adding, `print("\(String(data: snapshot.data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")`
  or similar just before `let decoded = try snapshot.data...`, to display what you are trying to decode.

Comment: I solved problem with [String: CustomModel]